# How to generate wsdl

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am working for the first time on SOAP. After going through various tutorials I have been able to create a small and simple soap server which offers two functions. Although I have been able to create the SOAP service and test it with a client I am not being able to understand WSDL even after going through the tutorials e.g. at http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_binding.asp .

So how can I make this SOAP "wsdl soap" ?? Is there anyway way to autogenerate it in PHP? I don't mind writting it down manually provided I know what to write. Where do I put what code to make it "wsdl" ??

```
function geolocate(double $lat, double $lng)
{
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat='.$lat.'&lng='.$lng.'&username=imranomar');
    return $contents;
}

function describe(long $geonameid)
{
    return file_get_contents('http://ws.geonames.org/get?geonameId='.$geonameid.'&style=full');
}

$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "urn://localhost/firstmobile?wsdl"));
$server->addFunction('geolocate');
$server->addFunction('describe');
$server->handle();
```

**Note: I cannot be using any framwork**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568916/generating-wsdl-when-using-phps-native-soap-class

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Zend_Soap_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.server.html) as it simplify webservices developpement in PHP.

It is possible to auto generate SOAP WSDL using [Zend AutoDiscovery](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html)

Comment: i am sorry but that is not an option. I cannot be using any framwork.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why not use the framework? otherwise, you gonna need to write the wsdl manually, or use a wsdl generator